# Webdriver - issues with fluent wait and IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and webdriver to automate a test. This test is for 2 dropdowns, and has drilldown functionality. So, the first dropdown contains a list of options, and the second one will be populated differently based on what the user selects in the first. I am trying to test selecting all the different options in the first dropdown, and verifying that the correct options are available in the second dropdown. For example, the first dropdown could have choices A and B. If I select A, the second dropdown will have choices 1, 2, and 3. If I select B, the second dropdown will have choices 8, 9, and 10.

I was having an issue when changing the values in the first dropdown. When I selected A, webdriver would try to check to see if 1, 2, and 3 were available in the 2nd dropdown before it was loaded. This was causing my tests to fail.

To resolve this issue, I added a fluent wait for the second dropdown. So, if I chose either A or B in the first dropdown, it would wait until the 2nd dropdown loaded before checking the available options. This solution worked great for testing in chrome and firefox. However, it does not help when using IE10. When I run the test in IE10, it is still trying to check the values of the second dropdown before they are loaded, which causes my test to fail.

Has anyone come across issues with fluent wait when using IE. The only way I have been able to get it to work in IE, is to add a sleep line. if I use something like sleep(2000), it seemed to work. However, that could still cause my tests to fail if the web page were running slow and took longer to load.

Here is the code I am using for fluent wait. I am selecting a value from the first dropdown. Then I use smartSleep to wait for the 2nd dropdown, and then check the values in that dropdown. Please let me know if more information is needed to help understand the issue I am having.

```
public void smartSleep(String selector){
        //log.info("INFO: waiting for the selector to appear");
        fluentWaitPresent(selector);
        log.info("INFO: Smart Sleep waited for: " +selector);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for IE10 is to wait for the page to load. I was previously waiting for an element to appear on the page, but sometimes IE wouldn't find the element even though it was displayed. Below is the wait method I am using, which has been working for all versions of IE

```
public boolean waitForPageLoaded(RCLocationExecutor driver) throws Exception {
            String fluentWaitTimeout = customParameters.get(CustomParameterNames.FLUENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
            log.info("INFO: setting the fluent wait timeout at: "+fluentWaitTimeout);
                Wait<RCLocationExecutor> wait = new FluentWait<RCLocationExecutor>(driver)
                        .withTimeout(Long.valueOf(fluentWaitTimeout), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .ignoring(ElementNotFoundException.class);

               return wait.until(new Function<RCLocationExecutor, Boolean>(){

                        public Boolean apply(RCLocationExecutor driver){                                
                            return  driver.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                        }});    
    }
```